# How to mirror Sharepoint 2007 site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, mirroring, mirror

I'm not sure if this should be posted here or over superuser, but how does one go about mirroring a Sharepoint 2007 site? I have admin access, and the mirror doesn't need to be nice and pretty; it just needs to be presentable and readable. Also, I need all the shared docs to be copied as well.

We use to have WinHTTrack to mirror the Sharepoint, but that broke a few months ago due to some of our recent security changes. I tried the username@password:domain method but that resulted no luck.

Comment: How often do you mirror the sites?

Comment: I like to mirror it at least once a week. Thanks.

Comment: There are commercial solutions, would you consider that?

Comment: @Trikks any way I can do away with some free tools?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little bit on how and where you want to mirror it.

If you have a separate SharePoint farm (even a single server - one tier - farm), you can rely on backup / restore, export / import or content deployment to have another copy up and running that will be a mirror of the existing one.

If you want an offline version, depends on what kind of content you need (collaboration stuff ?) you can use Microsoft Groove 2007 that offers an offline mode for some of the targeted data.

Comment: I've opted for WinHTTrack because I need the Sharepoint to be offline and static. The SP consists of a bunch of procedures and documents for the on-call techs when there's an emergency, which assumes the main servers are offline. Would this work?

Comment: You'll be able to grab whatever is reachable by the spider but I'm not sure about all the UI stuff. Server side handled stuff like sorting, checking for version, etc. will fail for sure. Do you need the documents (and possible metadata associated) or you really need a portal that you can browse and "work with" ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this great tool that can mirror the SP site for cheap: http://www.metaproducts.com/OEPR.html

Answer (score 0):

If WinHTTrack did satisfy you, why not just fix it?

There are solutions around the web to have WinHTTrack work with NTLM authentication: http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/7513/index.html

However the download link seems to be broken (geocities..), but you could try to search for [NTML proxy](https://www.google.lv/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ntlm%20proxy) solutions and try to setup your own.

Comment: Actually, WinHTTrack did not satisfy me. ALl those posts on their forum and website are old. Since then, MS has pushed out patches to fix those holes.

I was able to find a proxy, but it was written in Python, it wasn't running right on a Windows machine.